# Добавление функционала в js игру "Верю/не верю"

Tags: javascript, html, css, веб-программирование

Делаю игру на js игру "Верю/не верю". На экране поочередно появляются заголовки утверждений. Пользователь отвечает на каждое утверждение поочередно. Всего 5 утверждений. - Если пользователь нажал на кнопку Неправда тогда появляется следующее утверждение. А если правда тогда появляется описание. К следующему вопросу можно перейти нажав на белый кружочек, которые под заголовками, который превращается в красный, если уже был дан ответ на него (любой) или нажав на дальше.

Вопрос:

1. Как оптимальнее всего сделать так, чтобы вопросы сменялись без перезагрузки страницы;
2. Как сделать навигацию по вопросам в виде кружочков снизу и кружочки были активными на чистом js? Имеющийся код и примерный вид функционала ниже:

```html
<h1>Утверждение 1</h1>
<div id="text" style="display:none;">Объяснение утверждения</div>
<button onclick="chpok('text')"><h2 onclick="chpok('arrow')">Правда</h2></button>
<button onclick="chpok('arrow')"><h2>Неправда</h2></button>
<h2 id="arrow" onclick="chpok('block1')" style="display:none;">Дальше</h2>

<div class="block1" id="block1" style="display: none;">
  <h1>Утверждение 2</h1>
  <div id="text2" style="display:none;">Объяснение утверждения</div>
  <button onclick="chpok('text2')"><h2 onclick="chpok('arrow2')">Правда</h2></button>
  <button onclick="chpok('arrow2')"><h2>Неправда</h2></button>
  <h2 id="arrow2" onclick="chpok('block2')" style="display:none;">Дальше</h2>
</div>

<div class="block2" id="block2" style="display: none;">
  <h1>Утверждение 3</h1>
  <div id="text3" style="display:none;">Объяснение утверждения</div>
  <button onclick="chpok('text3')"><h2 onclick="chpok('arrow3')">Правда</h2></button>
  <button onclick="chpok('arrow3')"><h2>Неправда</h2></button>
  <h2 id="arrow3" style="display:none;">Дальше</h2>
</div>

<script>function chpok(id) {
  elem=document.getElementById(id);
  state=elem.style.display;
  if (state=='none') elem.style.display='';
}</script>
```

[image: Примерно это выглядит так:]

Comment: А вопрос в чем? У вас уже есть реализация, что вас не устраивает?

Comment: У меня все слайды появляются на одной странице, а не сменяют друг друга, и я не знаю как добавить навигацию в виде кружочков, Обновлю вопрос

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const data = [
  {stmt: "Утверждение 1", desc: "Объяснение утверждения 1"},
  {stmt: "Утверждение 2", desc: "Объяснение утверждения 2"},
  {stmt: "Утверждение 3", desc: "Объяснение утверждения 3"},
];

let curStmt = 0;

function showStmt(idx) {
  document.getElementById('progress-item-' + curStmt).classList.remove('current');
  curStmt = idx;
  document.getElementById('stmt').innerText = data[idx].stmt;
  document.getElementById('desc').innerText = data[idx].desc;
  document.getElementById('progress-item-' + idx).classList.add('current');
  applyComplete(data[idx].complete);  
}

function applyComplete(val) {
  val = (val) ? true : false;
  document.getElementById('desc').style.visibility = (val) ? 'visible' : 'hidden';
  document.getElementById('btnTrue').disabled = val;   
  document.getElementById('btnFalse').disabled = val;   
}

function createProgressBar() {
  const parent = document.getElementById('progress');
  parent.innerHTML = '';
  for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    const item = document.createElement('div');
    item.setAttribute('data-idx', i);
    item.id = 'progress-item-' + i;
    item.classList.add('item');
    if (data[i].complete)
      item.classList.add('complete');
    parent.appendChild(item);
  }
}

function btnClick(val) {
  data[curStmt].complete = true;
  document.getElementById('progress-item-' + curStmt).classList.add('complete');
  if (val || (curStmt === data.length - 1)) {
    applyComplete(true);
  } else {
    showStmt(curStmt + 1);
  }
}

document.getElementById('progress').addEventListener(
  'click',
  function (e) {
    if (e.target.classList.contains('item')) {
      const newIdx = e.target.getAttribute('data-idx') - 0;
      if (newIdx != curStmt) {
        showStmt(newIdx);
      }
    }
  },
  true
);

createProgressBar();
showStmt(0);
```

```css
.section {
  margin: 10px 0;
}

#progress .item {
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  margin: 0 5px;
  border: 2px solid red;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#progress .item.current {
  border-color: blue;
}

#progress .item.complete {
  background-color: green;
}

#progress .item:not(.complete):hover {
  background-color: lime;
}
```

```html
<div class="section">
  <div id="stmt"></div>
  <div id="desc"></div>
</div>
<div class="section buttons">
  <button id="btnTrue" onclick="btnClick(true)">Правда</button>
  <button id="btnFalse" onclick="btnClick(false)">Ложь</button>
<div>
<div id="progress" class="section"></div>
```